# How to check if the site is angular

Tags: angular

Could someone advise how to check if the platform used for an internal site is angular or non angular?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try : http://www.builtwith.com/ and enter the url. Do you want to check automatically via a program by passing into a url??

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Blastfreak but unfortunately I got this error message when entering the site:
We hate errors but one just occurred.   

and we're truly sorry about that.

Things you can do -

    Try going back to the last page
    Go back to the homepage and start again
    Send us an email and we will try and fix the issue    --I suppose it's because it's an internal site.

Comment: Umm I guess that not angular js specific issue. Its little difficult to guess the issue unless we have few more details.

Comment: `internal site`... I guess builtwith.com needs to access the site to inspect it

Comment: Yep, that's the point, I can't use builtwith.com because my site can not be accessed. But I forgot to mention it in the beginning - my fault..

Answer (score 2):

for **angular 5** and below ,In your Chrome browser open the Angular site https://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/

press <kbd>F12</kbd> then go to console and type `angular`

> angular {element: ƒ, bootstrap: ƒ, copy: ƒ, extend: ƒ, equals: ƒ, …}

In angular site it will give output similar to above .
For none angular it throws an error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
> at :1:1[image: for angular site]

[image: For none angular site]

Comment: this test failed for website made in angular6, not sure about others.

Comment: Yes commands like angular , and angular.version does not work  for the latest sites as https://angular.io/

Comment: Although `window.ng` worked for angular 6 but seems like all these methods are just unreliable in getting this information. Only if there was a real proper way to do that in javascript. I am working on a problem where i need to initialize a separate angular app within the same page conditionally only if no other angular is initialized already that may interfere with mine or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Chrome extension AngularJS Inspector. Great for developing in Angular and certainly gets you what you want.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-inspector/gjhmfjbfdbeeekiijofbikifokdkfhcc

Answer (score 1):

I use chrome dev tools (F12) to view all the .js files.
Go to the 'network' tab, filter only '.js' files and have a look at the preview of the content, you might see some clues.
For example, I saw in some sites a .js file of angular with comment of the angular version (1.5.8)

**Another option:**
Try this site: https://www.similartech.com
It has an option to enter a site URL and it will show what technologies it uses.